# Query 6 different columns with 6 numbers in all combinations sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database with 6 columns, n1 - n6. each has a number in it, so each row has 6 different numbers. When I query I am checking the 6 numbers I have to submit against each row in the database. I need the query to change the combination so in theory 36 queries are done.

So an example dataset might be

```
N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  N6
1   12  54  36  17  23
```

and the numbers I have to query against this would be

1 54 36 17 23 12

so they are the same but because they are in a different order it would not return a result. All 6 must match to return positive.

Example query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE n1 = :n1 AND n2 = :n2 AND n3 = :n3 AND n4 = :n4 AND n5 = :n5 AND n6 = :n6";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":n1", $n1);
$stmt->bindParam(":n2", $n2);
$stmt->bindParam(":n3", $n3);
$stmt->bindParam(":n4", $n4);
$stmt->bindParam(":n5", $n5);
$stmt->bindParam(":n6", $n6);
$stmt->execute();
```

I could do this with 36 different queries, but to be able to do it in one would be much more usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . Storing six numbers in a row sounds like a bad data format.  If these were rows instead of columns, then it would be easier.

However, assuming no duplicates, you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM numbers
WHERE n1 IN (:n1, :n2, :n3, :n4, :n5, :n6) AND
      n2 IN (:n1, :n2, :n3, :n4, :n5, :n6) AND
      n3 IN (:n1, :n2, :n3, :n4, :n5, :n6) AND
      n4 IN (:n1, :n2, :n3, :n4, :n5, :n6) AND
      n5 IN (:n1, :n2, :n3, :n4, :n5, :n6) AND
      n6 IN (:n1, :n2, :n3, :n4, :n5, :n6);
```

Comment: This breaks down down if values are repeated. e.g. row has values 1, 1,54,36,17,23 and search is 23,17,36,54,12,1.

Comment: @Matt . . . The answer explicitly says that it works if the values are not repeated.  The question does not explain what to do in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (n1 INT, n2 INT, n3 INT, n4 INT, n5 INT, n6 INT);
INSERT INTO YourTable (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6)
VALUES (1,12,54,36,17,23);

CREATE TABLE ValuesTable (Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,Value INT, primary key(id));
INSERT INTO ValuesTable (Value) VALUES (1),(12),(54),(36),(17),(23);

SELECT t.*
FROM
    YourTable t
    INNER JOIN (
       SELECT
          v1.Value as n1
          ,v2.Value as n2
          ,v3.Value as n3
          ,v4.Value as n4
          ,v5.Value as n5
          ,v6.Value as n6
       FROm
          ValuesTable v1
          INNER JOIN ValuesTable v2
          ON v1.Id <> v2.Id
          INNER JOIN ValuesTable v3
          ON v1.Id <> v3.Id
          AND v2.Id <> v3.Id
          INNER JOIN ValuesTable v4
          ON v1.Id <> v4.Id
          AND v2.Id <> v4.Id
          AND v3.Id <> v4.Id
          INNER JOIN ValuesTable v5
          ON v1.Id <> v5.Id
          AND v2.Id <> v5.Id
          AND v3.Id <> v5.Id
          AND v4.Id <> v5.Id
          INNER JOIN ValuesTable v6
          ON v1.Id <> v6.Id
          AND v2.Id <> v6.Id
          AND v3.Id <> v6.Id
          AND v4.Id <> v6.Id
          AND v5.Id <> v6.Id
    ) v
    ON t.n1 = v.n1
    AND t.n2 = v.n2
    AND t.n3 = v.n3
    AND t.n4 = v.n4
    AND t.n5 = v.n5
    AND t.n6 = v.n6
;
```

By adding your 6 numbers into a table/temp table with an auto increment on it by using 6 inner joins you can generate all of the permutations (6 factorial or 720 combinations) and then inner join to your table and get your desired result.  By using an Id field it will allow for repeated numbers in your list e.g. 1, 12, 12, ....

Another option is to re-order your table it self by combining all of your columns into a single column and after that you can then join on a temp table of your 6 values and count to make sure 6 joined or you can reorder the columns and use conditional aggregation to make then into columns again and test the same order as in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you may have duplicates, and you have a primary key (`id` in the example below):

```
select a.* from numbers a
inner join 
(select id, group_concat(n order by n asc separator ' ') as n from (
  select id, n1 as n from numbers
  union all
  select id, n2 as n from numbers
  union all
  select id, n3 as n from numbers
  union all
  select id, n4 as n from numbers
  union all
  select id, n5 as n from numbers
  union all
  select id, n6 as n from numbers
) b group by id) c on a.id = c.id 
where c.n = '1 12 17 23 36 54';
```

The only requirement is the numbers you are querying are concatenated into a string with ascending order.

[example in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e9394/1)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple logic using **UNION ALL** operator with **count** check.

Consider below table contains the data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Table1', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.Table1;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (n1 INT, n2 INT, n3 INT, n4 INT, n5 INT, n6 INT);

INSERT INTO Table1 (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6)
VALUES (13,12,54,34,17,23);

INSERT INTO Table1 (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6)
VALUES (1,12,54,36,17,23);
```

And here is your input, the data we are going to check in the table .

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#MyInput', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #MyInput; 

CREATE TABLE dbo.#MyInput (Id INT NOT NULL identity(1,1),Value INT, primary key(id));

INSERT INTO #MyInput (Value) VALUES (12),(13),(54),(36),(17),(23);
```

Here comes the key step. You have to apply UNION ALL operator on all the columns in your base table, ie. Table1 with row number.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#NumberedTable1','U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #NumberedTable1
GO

SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY n1) Rno, n1 value
 INTO #NumberedTable1
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY n1) Rno, n2 
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY n1) Rno, n3
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY n1) Rno, n4
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY n1) Rno, n5
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY n1) Rno, n6
FROM Table1
```

The following loop will check whether the input records will match with the numbers stored in your table.
If matches with any of the stored data,you will get the printed result. You can change the mode of output as you wish.. :)

```
DECLARE @MaxLoop int
SELECT @MaxLoop=MAX(Rno)
FROM #NumberedTable1

WHILE (@MaxLoop>=1)

BEGIN
IF (SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM #NumberedTable1 t
            JOIN #MyInput b ON t.Rno=@MaxLoop and t.value=b.Value)=6 -- SPECIFY THE COLUMN COUNT 
    BEGIN

    Print'Combination exists';
    BREAK;

    END
 ELSE
  BEGIN
   SET @MaxLoop=@MaxLoop-1
    IF @MaxLoop=-0
    Print'Combination does not exists'
   END
 END
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: row_number() doesn't exist in my sql and the loops are generally not good in sql for performance